# Removing Endless OS to install Fedora

Tags: linux, fedora

I've bought a new Asus laptop and it has an Endless OS installed.

I want Fedora to be my only os so I've installed Fedora from USB but Endless is still on my laptop and I can't access Fedora and get rid of Endless.

How do I remove Endless in order to have Fedora as my only OS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

During the install process of Fedora how are you selecting disk space? On that screen during install you should be able to blow away all other partitions and create new ones for Fedora.

Comment: I've chosen the auto option, it's shown me my 2 discs and I've chosen the SSD drive to be partitioned automatically.

Comment: Cool. If you are sure you don't want endless, you can select both drives and remove the partitions then let it auto partition. That should blow away endless. I *think* by default in Fedora auto partition looks to install in free space and not overwrite existing installs.

Comment: When I delete all those partitions from 2 drivers they don't really get deleted. What should I click in fedora installation menu?

Comment: Use a partition manager to delete partitions or follow the official documentation: https://docs.fedoraproject.org/f28/install-guide/install/Installing_Using_Anaconda.html#sect-installation-gui-storage-partitioning Fair warning: if you have to ask for help at this stage then you don't really know how to use computers and research the internet to find already existing answers to your questions. You are going to make your life worse following this path. You should keep Endless OS.